# Create wallet instance from existing file system wallet

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In fabric-samples, when you start the application-javascript, it builds a wallet using the following:

```
const wallet = await buildWallet(walletPath);
```

I want to use a file system wallet so the `walletPath` points to, say, `/wallet` directory.  When I restart the network and submit a transaction, I need to create the Gateway first using the wallet.  But the `walletPath` already exists.  How do I create a `Wallet` instance given an existing `walletPath`?  Do I need to call `buildWallet` again?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to say is that, if you are using (or can use) Fabric v2.4+, you should use the [Fabric Gateway client API](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/) instead of the [legacy Node SDK](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/). The Fabric Gateway client API does not require a wallet.

With the Node SDK, the Wallet (or rather the WalletStore that backs the Wallet) just provides a storage location for your client credentials. These typically consist of the Member Services Provider (MSP) ID of the organization that your client identity belongs to, an X.509 certificate, and associated private key.

To use existing client credentials, just create a Wallet pointing at the existing location. For a FileSystemWallet, this would be the wallet directory. If you have created a new network with new client credentials, you probably want to create a FileSystemWallet pointing at a new (empty) directory and populate that with your new client credentials. You could pick a different directory name or, if you no longer need the old credentials, delete the old wallet directory to start fresh.

This tutorial might help clarify how wallets work:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-wallet.html

Comment: To "create a Wallet pointing at the existing location", you mean `new Wallet(walletPath)`?

Comment: With the v2.2 Node SDK, it would be `await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet('/path/to/existing/wallet/directory')`

Comment: oh so newFileSystemWallet creates the wallet if not exisitng; but will just return existing wallet when called

Comment: Yes. The FileSystemWallet is just a view on a directory used to store identities. If the directory is empty (or does not exist) then the wallet is empty. If the directory already contains identity information, the wallet allows you to access them